# Inkscape: keyboard shortcut for Break Path At Selected Nodes

Tags: inkscape, shortcuts

I've been searching long time for keyboard shortcuts for these actions in Inkscape.
[image]

- Join selected nodes
- Break path at selected nodes
- Join selected endnodes with a new segment
- Delete segment between two non-endpoint nodes

Do they exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating this question FINALLY answered it for myself!

See https://inkscape.org/doc/keys092.html.
I was always searching for shortcuts for "Break path at selected nodes", but in the above document it is listed under the description "Break selected node(s)". Creating this question made me look for the other actions as well, some of which are listed by their correct description.

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> : Join selected nodes
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> : Break path at selected nodes
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> : Join selected endnodes with a new segment
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> : Delete segment between two non-endpoint nodes

Hope this can be of use to others!

Answer (score 0):

The [keyboard and mouse reference](https://inkscape.org/doc/keys092.html#idm3069) says:

> Join/break
>
> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> join selected nodes This requires that exactly two end nodes
>   within the path be selected. You can lock the position of one of the
>   two joined nodes by hovering mouse over it.
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> join selected end nodes with new segment
>
> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> break selected node(s) After break, only one of each two new
>   nodes is selected. May apply to more than one node.
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> delete segment between pairs of adjacent selected nodes

I just tested these on 0.92 and they work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response as well! It seems like Alt+Backspace and Alt+Del are the same, just verified that.  It's a shame that the keyboard and mouse reference doesn't use the same description as the tooltip, which could have saved us some research.